# Change separator symbol for backreferences

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I need to change `/` into `,` (comma followed by the space) in backreferences in my bibliography.

So instead

> (Zitiert auf S. 3/4/99/101)

I need:

> (Zitiert auf S. 3, 4, 99, 101)

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1998,
    Address = {Berlin and New York and Freiburg},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {Athanasius Werke - Die dogmatischen Schriften},
    Call-Number = {TH: Vb 17.02-1.1.2},
    Date-Added = {2010-10-16 13:24:30 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-13 17:12:32 +0000},
    Editor = {Marin Tetz and others},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {109-175},
    Publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
    Read = {No},
    Series = {Urkunden zur Geschichte des Arianischen Streites 318-328},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {Ar. 1},
    Title = {Oratio I contra Arianos},
    Volume = {1, Tl. 1, Lfg. 2},
    Year = {1998}}
@incollection{evagrius2011,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Evagrius Scholasticus}},
    Booktitle = {{\'E}vagre Le Scholastique: Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique - Livres I-III},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va1.05/542},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-24 12:11:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:31 +0000},
    Editor = {Joseph Bidez and Leon Parmentier},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {Evagr.},
    Shorttitle = {h.e.},
    Title = {Historia ecclesiastica},
    Volume = {542},
    Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  backrefpage  = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
  backrefpages = {Zitiert auf S\adddot},
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{athanasius1998}
\pagebreak
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 11]{athanasius1998}
\pagebreak
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the delimiter only for the `pageref` list, use

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{%
  \renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \ifnumless{\abx@pagerefstyle}{0}
    {\usebibmacro{list:plain}%
     \ifhyperref
       {\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}}
       {#1}}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:init}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{pageref:comp}{#1}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:dump}}
       {}}}
\makeatother
```

This is a copy of the original definition from `biblatex.def` with `\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%` added.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
```

[image]

I would also advise you to use utf8 everywhere, to input accents directly, to get the endash right, and to use biber instead of bibtex.

```
 {Évagre Le Scholastique: Histoire Ecclésiastique -- Livres ...}
```

Comment: I thought this is solution but once I implemented it in my main file I realised that this is changing something else that it shouldn't. In the case where I have more than one `Address` entries (more than one cities) this changes first entry to comma and the other ones are left with slash. I changed my MWE above so that you can test it and see what I mean. It produces `Berlin, New York/Freiburg`in this case instead `Berlin, New York, Freiburg`

Comment: Add `\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\addcomma\addspace}` if you want the commas in the address. If you want slashes you need a solution like that from @moeve and change one of the list formats to use special formatting.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great answer for those who want to change both address and list formats!